# Tic-tac-toe grid gui in python pyglet

Tags: python-3.9

```
import pyglet
from pyglet import shapes

title = " Tic-tac-toe "

window = pyglet.window.Window(500,500, title)
batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

def drawBoard(shape_list, batch=None):
    for i in range(100, 600, 100):
        linex = shapes.Line(i, 1, i, 600, width=3, color=(0, 230, 0), batch=batch)
        linex.opacity = 400
        shape_list.append(linex)
        liney = shapes.Line(1, i, 600, i, width=3, color=(0, 230, 0), batch=batch)
        liney.opacity = 400
        shape_list.append(liney)

shape_list = []
drawBoard(shape_list, batch=batch)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    batch.draw()



pyglet.app.run()
```

trying to make a tic-tac-toe grid in python pyglet but, I get this and am not able to make a grid of tic-tac-toe this problem is like a fishbone in my neck.

[this is the output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2dsE.png)

Comment: Just want to make a grid not the whole game till now.

Comment: Is your question how to get a 3x3 grid rather than 5x5?

Comment: Yes, You are right bro the grid which is used in tic-tac-toe.

Comment: `range(100, 600, 100)` <- this will loop from 100 to 600 (exclusive), in steps of 100 (5 times). So you should make sure to loop the proper amount of times, and then perhaps scale the points if you need a specific size.

Comment: The size of my window is really small.

Comment: So, Is it help me to do it without adjusting the window size.

Comment: Or it is shown my output at bottom of the screen can I adjust its alignment.

Comment: when I adjust my screen size.

Comment: Start by fixing your for-loop, so you get the correct amount of lines. Then figure out what you need to adjust in the 4 first parameters to `Line`. Your window is 500x500, so maybe store those in variables, so you can say e.g. `WIDTH / 3`.